# I'm getting this error and need help fixing it if possible.I'm trying to build my project to see the output but it won't let me

Tags: c#, visual-studio, error-handling

CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Timer' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer'
This is the error code I am receiving and I believe its the reason I cannot build my project. My professor hosted a zoom meeting and made a youtube video and this is some of the code he wrote out and we went over.

```
namespace DataCollector
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    private DispatcherTimer timer;
    MeasureLengthDevice measurementDevice = null;
    MainViewData displayData = new MainViewData();

    Frame frame = null;
    MainPage page = null;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        timer = new Timer(Timer_Tick, null, (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds, 
(int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15).TotalMilliseconds);
        measurementDevice = new MeasureLengthDevice();

        displayData = new MainViewData
        {
            Measurement = measurementDevice.ToString(),
            History = measurementDevice.History
        };

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
        page = (MainPage)frame.Content;
        measure.Text = measurementDevice.Measurement.ToString();
        measureHistory.Text = measurementDevice.History;
    }

    private async void Timer_Tick(object state)
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
() =>
        {
            if (page != null)
            {
                page.measure.Text = measurementDevice.Measurement.ToString();
            }
            displayData.History = measurementDevice.History;
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: According to the error you shown, I suggest that you can modify the code  'timer = new Timer(Timer_Tick, null, (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds, 
(int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15).TotalMilliseconds);' to 'timer'= new DispatcherTimer();. If you want to know more about the dispactchtimer, you can refer to [DispatcherTimer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer?view=winrt-18362#examples).

Answer (score 0):

The code is obviously wrong and there's no way to fix it without more context. However you really should ask your professor why it's not working instead of posting your question on Stack Overflow.